# Android Studio main activity menu missing

Tags: android, android-studio, menu

menu folder and menu_main.xml is missing from android studio? can anyone help how i can add this to android studio or why its missing and the possible solutions. Please check attached image for reference. Thanks in advance.
[MISSING MENU IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/musc3.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add it back in. Right-click on the res node and select New | Android Resource. Then select resource type menu and name it menu_main

Comment: thanks a lot, that helped. I am new do android so this must have seemed like a lame question.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't delete it,perhaps you move it into another folder, try to press `double shift` and type `menu_main` in the search bar, you will find it.